# Using async data with provide

Tags: vue.js

I have a problem with provide. I want to use my data in router-view with provide. When i use provide with data, it gives me an empty array. How can i use it with async data ?

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <the-sidebar></the-sidebar>
    <the-main>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </the-main>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  components: {
    TheSidebar,
    TheMain,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      stories: [],
      works: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchData(resource) {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/" + resource);
      const data = await res.json();

      return data;
    },
  },
  async created() {
    this.posts = await this.fetchData("posts");
    this.stories = await this.fetchData("stories");
    this.works = await this.fetchData("works");
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      stories: this.stories,
      posts: this.posts,
      works: this.works,
    };
  },
};
```

[Vue.js devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1M1Q.png)

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting back empty lists? Do you have server-side results or code?

Comment: I added vue.js devtools output

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1M1Q.png

Comment: Provide is not reactive in Vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `provide` & `inject` is not reactive in Vue. And should not be used as a reactive properties. The reason for this is because you could ease mutate the data in some ChildComponent. This would be very hard to debbugg in a large application.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject

> Note: the provide and inject bindings are NOT reactive. This is
> intentional. However, if you pass down an observed object, properties
> on that object do remain reactive.

*There is a work around to actually make it be reactive, but if you are learning Vue, this is not a good time to do it.*

**Suggestion**:
The best solution for you is to use `props`, and pass it down to ChildComponent like this:

```
<router-view :stories="stories" :posts="posts" :works="works"></router-view>
```

Just remember to register them in the ChildComponent:

```
props: ['stories', 'posts', 'works'],
```

Props are reactive properties and were made for this kind of use cases.

Comment: Why is that a minus? ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

There is one way you can overcome this problem with the help of Watchers.
Let me explain:-

> Parent component

```
provide() {
    return {    
    settings: this.settings
    }
},
```

*OR*

```
provide() {
    return {    
    settings: computed(() => (
        {...this.settings }))  
    }
}
```

> Child Component

```
<template>
    <section class="favorite-cat"> 
        <img v-if="injectCheck" :src="settings.url" alt="Cat" />
     </section>
</template>

<script>
inject: ['settings'],
 data() {
            return {
                injectCheck: false;
        };
    },

 watch: {
        'settings.value': function(newSettings, oldSettings) {
            if (!newSettings) return;
            this.injectCheck = true;
        },
    }
</script>
```

Happy Coding!!